# email in laravel 10 does not work in productionem in cpanel

Tags: laravel, email, cpanel, laravel-10

I've been trying for a day to make sending an email not working, for a moment I thought it was the server that wasn't working, but testing with another server wasn't working either, I've already checked both my credentials and the email I'm sending but the email is not sending, so I decided to use debug and the only clue I have is this.

```
< 220-br106.hostgator.com.br ESMTP Exim 4.95 #2 Wed, 21 Jun 2023 21:01:24 -0300
< 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited,
< 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
> EHLO \[127.0.0.1\]
> \< 250-\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* Hello \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* \[**\]
> \< 250-SIZE 52428800
> \< 250-8BITMIME
> \< 250-PIPELINING
> \< 250-PIPE_CONNECT
> \< 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
> \< 250 HELP
> AUTH LOGIN
> \< 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
> dXBsb2FuQHZqcnN6Y29kZS5jb20uYnI=
> \< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
> XkZrdVkhXVtaQ08o
> \< 235 Authentication succeeded
> MAIL FROM:\<**\>
> \< 250 OK
> RCPT TO:\<\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\>
> \< 250 Accepted
> DATA
> \< 354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
> .
> \< 250 OK id=1qC7lM-001QtL-3I
> """\
```

it authenticates but does not send

I'm trying because I want to upload my server and I can't

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.